# Safari (not others) always being forced to make XMLHttpRequest on Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, safari

I have the strangest problem. I just set up a Wordpress site using nginx and fastcgi_cache and it correctly caches in Firefox and Chrome (and returns the X-Cache header in the response) but not in Safari.

What is even stranger is that a page that is php but outside the Wordpress tree DOES correctly cache (and return cache header) in ALL browsers including Safari.

What happens in Safari is that for some reason it is always being forced to make an XHR request (after making a normal GET) to retrieve any Wordpress page (and returns no X-Cache header), while all other browsers are making a normal GET method request. And on the php page that is outside my Wordpress system, Safari makes a normal GET request.

I should add that I have tried Safari on 4 separate computers with the same result.

So far, I am stumped. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**: I checked out an easyengine configured wordpress site and found that safari works fine with that one, cache headers are reporting fine and no XHR...

**UPDATE 2**: I found that this was related to a single plugin YITH request a quote premium, I have contacted them to find out why it causes this strange behavior in Safari

Comment: Have you filed a Webkit bug about that?

Comment: No I wasn’t sure if it was something about my setup yet